# jQuery onClick icon type - change all image urls

Tags: jquery, html

I have 4+ different types of icon sets and need to change image url for all onClicking each link everytime

> **Want to change the image src (partially) based on relevant link click**

Eg:

```
<ul id="iconType">
  <li><a href="javascript:;" id="circleIcons">Circle icons</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:;" id="squareIcons">Square icons</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:;" id="grayIcons">Gray icons</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:;" id="sketchIcons">Sketch icons</a></li>
</ul>


<div id="selectedIcons">
  <img src="/Images/facebook-circle-icon.png" />
  <img src="/Images/twitter-circle-icon.png" />
  <img src="/Images/linkedin-circle-icon.png" />
  <img src="/Images/youtube-circle-icon.png" />
</div>
```

If I click on **squareIcons** link, all image urls should change like below

```
<div id="selectedIcons">
  <img src="/Images/facebook-square-icon.png" />
  <img src="/Images/twitter-square-icon.png" />
  <img src="/Images/linkedin-square-icon.png" />
  <img src="/Images/youtube-square-icon.png" />
</div>
```

If I click on **grayIcons** link, all image urls should change like below

```
<div id="selectedIcons">
  <img src="/Images/facebook-my-gray-icon.png" />
  <img src="/Images/twitter-my-gray-icon.png" />
  <img src="/Images/linkedin-my-gray-icon.png" />
  <img src="/Images/youtube-my-gray-icon.png" />
</div>
```

**and so on...**

jQuery :(

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#circleIcons').on('click', function(){
    $('#selectedIcons img').attr('src').replace('square','circle');
  });

  $('#squareIcons').on('click', function(){
    $('#selectedIcons img').attr('src').replace('circle','square');
  });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lxmm2ypr/)

Comment: where is the **facebook-square-icon.png** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#iconType a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var iconExtension = $(this).attr("data-extension");
    
    $("#img-facebook").attr('src', `/Images/facebook-${iconExtension}.png`);
    $("#img-twitter").attr('src', `/Images/twitter-${iconExtension}.png`);
    $("#img-linkedin").attr('src', `/Images/linkedin-${iconExtension}.png`);
    $("#img-youtube").attr('src', `/Images/youtube-${iconExtension}.png`);
   
    // you can skip the below code. It just shows the src url 
    $("#img-facebook").attr('alt', `/Images/facebook-${iconExtension}.png`);
    $("#img-twitter").attr('alt', `/Images/twitter-${iconExtension}.png`);
    $("#img-linkedin").attr('alt', `/Images/linkedin-${iconExtension}.png`);
    $("#img-youtube").attr('alt', `/Images/youtube-${iconExtension}.png`);
  });
});
```

```css
img{border: solid 1px red !important; margin: 5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="iconType">
  <li><a href="javascript:;" id="circleIcons" data-extension="circle-icon">Circle icons</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:;" id="squareIcons" data-extension="square-icon">Square icons</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:;" id="grayIcons" data-extension="gray-icon">Gray icons</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:;" id="sketchIcons" data-extension="sketch-icon">Sketch icons</a></li>
</ul>


<div id="selectedIcons">
  <img src="/Images/facebook-circle-icon.png" id="img-facebook"/> <br/>
  <img src="/Images/twitter-circle-icon.png" id="img-twitter"/> <br/>
  <img src="/Images/linkedin-circle-icon.png" id="img-linkedin"/> <br/>
  <img src="/Images/youtube-circle-icon.png" id="img-youtube"/> <br/>
</div>
```

Comment: you are **AWESOME**... Upvoted and Accepted your answer... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`.attr('src')` is a getter
`.attr('src', 'new string')` is the setter

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19532390)

Comment: @Rob this is the answer to the question. I just pointed out what's wrong in the code and provided the solution, how it is applied that's another problem.

Answer (score 0):

**first** you have num of `img` so you have to **loop** of all `img` and change one each time.

```
$('#circleIcons').on('click', function(){
$('#selectedIcons img').each(function() {
   $(this).attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace("old/directory", "new/directory"));
});
```

you have `each` function then `replace` the `src`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the `src` attribute and doing replacement, but you are not re-assigning to the `img` again. So you have to loop the items and assign with the updated `src` value.

```
 $('#squareIcons').on('click', function(){
   $('#selectedIcons img').each(function(){       
     var newsrc = $(this).attr('src').replace('_circle_','_square_');
     $(this).attr('src',newsrc);
  });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#circleIcons').on('click', function(){    
   $('#selectedIcons img').each(function(){       
       var newsrc = $(this).attr('src').replace('_circle_','_circle_');
       $(this).attr('src',newsrc);
    });
  });
 $('#squareIcons').on('click', function(){
    $('#selectedIcons img').each(function(){       
       var newsrc = $(this).attr('src').replace('_circle_','_square_');
       $(this).attr('src',newsrc);
    });   
  });
 $('#grayIcons').on('click', function(){
    $('#selectedIcons img').each(function(){       
       var newsrc = $(this).attr('src').replace('_circle_','_gray_');
       $(this).attr('src',newsrc);
    });
  });
 $('#sketchIcons').on('click', function(){
    $('#selectedIcons img').each(function(){       
       var newsrc = $(this).attr('src').replace('_circle_','_sketch_');
       $(this).attr('src',newsrc);
    }); 
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="iconType">
  <li><a href="javascript:;" id="circleIcons">Circle icons</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:;" id="squareIcons">Square icons</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:;" id="grayIcons">Gray icons</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:;" id="sketchIcons">Sketch icons</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="selectedIcons">
  <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/facebook_circle_color-256.png" width="32" height="32">
  <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/twitter_circle_color-256.png" width="32" height="32">
  <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/linkedin_circle_color-256.png" width="32" height="32">
  <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/youtube_circle_color-256.png" width="32" height="32">
  
</div>
```

**LOGIC IS WRONG.** The above snippet will work for the first time `click` event, because after the first click, we are changing to the new `src` value, but your code always looking for the old word `_circle_`, instead of the updated one. So you have to think on the logic part how you can fix that one.

**UPDATE:**

As per your question update, you are looking only for the changes of square with circle and vice versa. Here is the updated snippet for that functionality.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#circleIcons').on('click', function(){    
   $('#selectedIcons img').each(function(){       
       var newsrc = $(this).attr('src').replace('_square_','_circle_');
       $(this).attr('src',newsrc);
    });
  });
 $('#squareIcons').on('click', function(){
    $('#selectedIcons img').each(function(){       
       var newsrc = $(this).attr('src').replace('_circle_','_square_');
       $(this).attr('src',newsrc);
    });   
  });
 $('#grayIcons').on('click', function(){
    $('#selectedIcons img').each(function(){       
       var newsrc = $(this).attr('src').replace('_circle_','_gray_');
       $(this).attr('src',newsrc);
    });
  });
 $('#sketchIcons').on('click', function(){
    $('#selectedIcons img').each(function(){       
       var newsrc = $(this).attr('src').replace('_circle_','_sketch_');
       $(this).attr('src',newsrc);
    }); 
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="iconType">
  <li><a href="javascript:;" id="circleIcons">Circle icons</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:;" id="squareIcons">Square icons</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:;" id="grayIcons">Gray icons</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:;" id="sketchIcons">Sketch icons</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="selectedIcons">
  <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/facebook_circle_color-256.png" width="32" height="32">
  <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/twitter_circle_color-256.png" width="32" height="32">
  <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/linkedin_circle_color-256.png" width="32" height="32">
  <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/youtube_circle_color-256.png" width="32" height="32">
  
</div>
```